# Session timed out or not found while executing test in Selenoid using GitHub Actions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, github-actions, selenoid

When running a test in GitHub Actions throws an error. Can't figure out what the problem is. Help is needed.

**My test**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
 
driver = webdriver.Remote(
```

https://pastebin.com/V9Zfv4y1

**My workflow**

```
name: Tests
 
on: [push]
 
jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
```

https://pastebin.com/PrqYievL

**Error**

```
name: Tests
 
on: [push]
 
jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
```

https://pastebin.com/H324B51Q

**Problem solved by fixing Python script**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
```

https://pastebin.com/ATaSgUZp

Comment: Try increasing timeouts using [selenoid timeout flags](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_selenoid_cli_flags). E.g. `-timeout 300s`

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, again it gives an error. Attached the actual code in the description. Maybe there will be some other thoughts?